# Problems Installing Gtk and Webbkit for Python on Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygtk

I have been attempting to download Gtk3 and Webkkit to use to develop a web browser on Python. However, I am struggling to make it work.

I have successfully installed gtk+ 2.24.32_3 with Homebrew, however, I still have not been able to connect it to python.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
pip install PYGtk
```

That might help.

Comment: I get an error message: 
     'ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.'